# How to use Char in Switch Case

Tags: c++

> **How to make this work**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    main()
    {
        char C;
        printf("R=This Program gives you some of the information of the country you entered.");
        printf("Enter a Country:");
        scanf("%c", &C);
        switch(C)
        {
            case 'Algeria':
                printf("Capital: Algiers");
                printf("Currency and Country Code: Algerian Dinar (DZD)");
                break;
            }   



        getch ();
        return 0;
    }
```

> **The Error is**
>
> - 11 8   C:\Users\Edrian\Desktop\C++ Codes\World    Information.cpp  [Warning] character constant too long for its type
> - C:\Users\Edrian\Desktop\C++ Codes\World Information.cpp    In function    'int main()':
> - 11 8   C:\Users\Edrian\Desktop\C++ Codes\World    Information.cpp  [Warning] case label value exceeds maximum value for
>     type

Comment: Related: [Why the switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings)

Comment: Reminder:  a `char` or *character* is a single, one, letter or symbol.  A *string* is zero or more characters.  The `switch` works with *single* characters.

Answer (score 1):

Char contains only one character if you want to use more than one character you have to use string data type.In your case you should use string

Answer (score 1):

> 11 8 C:\Users\Edrian\Desktop\C++ Codes\World Information.cpp [Warning] character constant too long for its type

This says that `'Algeria'` is too long for the type `char`, which should be a single letter, e.g. `'A'` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54388000/6660678)).

```
    char string[256];
    scanf("%255s", string);
    switch (s[0]) {
        case 'A':
            if (0 == strcmp(string, "Algeria")) {
```

This should work.  You may need to `#include <string.h>` for `strcmp`.

Notice how `"Algeria"` is now double-quoted, while `'A'` is single-quoted.

I elided out lines that would be the same in both, mostly `printf` statements.  Make sure that you get the curly braces right.  I added a `{` for the `if`.  You'll need to add a `}` to match (before the `break;`).

You could also say

```
if (!strcmp(string, "Algeria")) {
```

But I thought that it might be easier for you to read the other way.  Functionally the two statements are the same, as C considers zero to be falsey.

See also:

- [Read no more than size of string with scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306591/6660678)
- [What's the difference between these 4 items:  character, array, string, literal in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29405410/6660678)
- [Does the C standard explicitly indicate truth value as 0 or 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37291681/6660678)
- [Why the switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/650162/6660678) (kudos to [Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976805/yksisarvinen) for [finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387977/how-to-use-char-in-switch-case#comment95588243_54387977))

Answer (score 0):

Know the difference :

'Algeria' this is a string literal so it should be "Algeria" and your C should be a string

'A' is a character